# Image XYZ values

Tags: python, image, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to interpolate an image.

I was able to extract the X and Y values of an image, but the interpolation requires the Z-value to be extracted.

```
im = Image.open('Sample.png')
im = np.array(im.convert('L'))

M, N = im.shape
nx, ny = im.shape[1], im.shape[0]
```

How can I extract the z-value where z = f(x,y)?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to use `im[y][x]`? Or what is `f` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the X and Y values as

```
x = np.arange(im.shape[1])
y = np.arange(im.shape[0])
```

The image data itself gives the Z values. The Z value at coordinate (`x[j]`, `y[i]`) is `im[i, j]`.